# Insert para cada registro encontrado - PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, procedure, oracle12c

bom dia.

Sou novo em Pl/sql e estou precisando realizar a inserção de 110 registros (Numero de 1 a 110)  em uma tabela ( tabela: vara) para cada ID da tabela foro_tribunal.

o Insert seria mais ou menos:

```
INSERT INTO vara(vara_id,foro_tribunal_id,nome) 
VALUES (VARA_SEQ.nextval,"TODOS OS FOROS TRIBUNAIS DA TABELA FORO_TRIBUNAL",'1 (DE 1 A 110)');
```

Tenho aproximadamente 97 mil registros na tabela foro_tribunal, daria aproximadamente 10.670.000 Inserts.

Qual seria a melhor forma para percorrer todos os registros da tabela foro_tribunal e inserir os 110 valores para cada registro encontrado ?

Comment: Para cada par de dados você quer inserir 110 registros iguais só variando o id gerado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta fazer isso.

```
INSERT INTO VARA (vara_id, foro_tribunal_id,nome)
SELECT id, nome FROM foro_tribunal
```

O oracle vai pegar os dados do select e fazer o insert.

Se necessário podes fazer um where no SELECT.

Neste artigo [aqui](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php) existem outros exemplos.

Comment: Opa. Obrigado pela resposta cara, mas dessa forma não funcionaria pois a subconsulta retornaria mais de uma linha. Mas Obrigado de qualquer forma !

Comment: Mas aqui a ideia é exatamente inserir tudo o que vier da subconsulta.

Comment: Cheguei a testar dessa forma, mas da erro informando que a subconsulta retorna mais de uma linha.

Comment: @GedanMagalhães Possívelmente é por que falta o seu ID que é proveniente de uma sequence. O que  você poderia fazer é adicionar uma trigger no Before Insert adicionando o ID com o próximo valor da sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Este caso pode ser útil em situações que temos de "criar" dados.

Usando a [chamada recursiva](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_GQMLEEPG5ARVSIFGQRD3SES92.html) do Oracle criamos uma sequencia artificial de N linhas.

```
select level from dual connect by level <= 101;
```

Peguemos agora a tabela de varas

```
select id from vara;
```

e colocamos os dois no mesmo select

```
select id 
from vara,
     (select level from dual connect by level <= 110) aux;
```

Deixando acontecer um [produto cartesiano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_cartesiano_(%C3%A1lgebra_relacional)) proposital

Isto é base pra um [insert](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/insert-select.html)

```
insert into foro_tribunal (vara_id,foro_tribunal_id,nome)
select vara.id,aux.level,aux.level||'/110')
    from vara,
         (select level from dual connect by level <= 110) aux;
```

Creio já ter sido resolvido , mas a ideia básica pode ser replicada.

Answer (score -1):

Creio que a melhor solução sela vc fazer dois loops. Um para correr toda a query principal, e outro para fazer as 110 inserções a cada registro lido da consulta principal. Faz um cursor para ler a query e depois um for de 1 até 110 para incluir os registros necessários.

Nesse Link http://aprendaplsql.com/plsql/cursores/ vc verá um exemplo sobre como criar um cursor.

Aí, dentro do cursor, vc faz um loop for, mais ou menos assim:

`FOR nVarCont IN 0..110 LOOP
/aqui entra o insert que vc deseja fazer/
insert into tabela (contador, outras_colunas) values (nVarCont, valores_outras_colunas);
END LOOP;`

Comment: Felipe, seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Considere adicionar mais informações à sua resposta, como um exemplo prático de como implementá-la e referências de documentações. Isso beneficia o autor da pergunta e futuras pessoas.

Comment: Grato pela observação!

Comment: Já que exumaram .. select level from dual connect by level <= 101 , gera uma sequencia artificial